# Windows 8.1 + DNSCrypt + Unbound for DNS Cache

Tags: windows, networking, dns

I'm following this guide (http://yvoinov.blogspot.it/2014/05/windows-7-unbound-dnscrypt.html) and others but nothing:

I have Windows 8.1 x64, DNSCrypt 1.4.3, Unbound last version downloaded from the site.

I started DNSCrypt on 127.0.0.1:53, changed my DNS setup in network card to 127.0.0.1 and I set this in service.conf of Unbound:

```
# Unbound configuration file on windows.
# See example.conf for more settings and syntax
server:
    # verbosity level 0-4 of logging
    verbosity: 4

    # if you want to log to a file use
    logfile: "C:\unbound.log"

    prefetch: yes
    prefetch-key: yes
    minimal-responses: yes
    do-ip4: yes   
    do-ip6: no  
    do-udp: yes
    do-not-query-localhost: no

    local-zone: "example.com" redirect
    local-data: "example.com A 127.0.0.1"

forward-zone:  
    name: "."
    forward-addr: 127.0.0.1@53
```

server: auto-trust-anchor-file: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Unbound\root.key"
Where I'm wrong?

If I go to example.com the site shows, also if Unbound have to redirect it to 127.0.0.1 as I set it.

This means that Unbound is not correctly configured and not works. Isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

`forward-addr: 127.0.0.1@53` doesn't make sense, since Unbound is probably also listening to port 53.

You need to have `dnscrypt-proxy` listen to a different port, such as `5353`, and forward to that port in Unbound's configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I installed **dnscrypt** with:

```
dnscrypt-proxy.exe -R “dnscrypt.eu-nl” -a 127.0.0.2:40 –install
```

& added at the end of:

**C:\Program Files (x86)\Unbound\service** :

```
##### Settings for dnscrypt #####
forward-zone:
name: “.”
forward-addr: 127.0.0.2@40
```

& in the Windows network interface properties set the `dns` server to `127.0.0.1` (`unbound` listens by default on port `53 @ 127.0.0.1 && ::1`)

Tested in Windows 10.